# How can I write a component for general use in modern frameworks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, svelte, sveltekit

I want to write a chat component in Svelte (and SvelteKit), and make it available to everyone through npm. I want to use it in a React project.

I researched it a bit but couldn't find any good answer about this. I saw that you can embed it but that's not what I'm looking for. I would rather make it a component like `<Chat />`.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: If you search for "svelte component library" you will get some examples of how others did it. For example : [threlte](https://github.com/grischaerbe/threlte) that have a `package/core` folder with what seems like a sveltekit project inside it.

Comment: @Poulpynator what I meant is I want to write it in SvelteKit, publish to npm, and use on React for example. This project seems like it's just written for Svelte

Comment: So you want to write a component for a framework to use it on another framework? Are you sure it's possible? Some component based frameworks like latest versions of Ionic are "framework agnostic", meaning they are made for this, is it the case for Svelte?

Comment: @Kaddath yes that's what I was asking specifically and couldn't find anything about it. It might not be possible on it's own but maybe somehow if we can write Web Components inside Svelte?

Comment: It could be possible, but then a "svelte component library" uses `svelte` as a dependency, using it in a react app will definitely involve installing svelte as a peer-dependency for installed component and what's he point? Is it safe? If it does work, then for how long? I recommend you either migrate the App entirely to a single framework (Biased opinion; `Sveltekit`), or have subdomains and websites for different app features. Also checkout https://astro.build/, its a framework that combines all frameworks.

Comment: My bad didn't read the question well, I am with @NatumanyaGuy it could be possible but it sounds like a bad idea for future you. The cleanest way I see would be to use [CustomElementRegistry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements) so you can either search for library that use that or use it directly yourself. As said previously the components created by svelte can be used only by svelte (which is the case for most frameworks).

Comment: Thank you guys, it seems like I'll go with the embed option for now as the project is already ready. Astro definitely seems like a good option for future, thanks a lot!